# Retrieving forwarded original email message

Tags: php, email

Is there a way to retrieve original body of the email that was forwarded without writing your own parser?

People will forward suitable emails to our service and we will have to parse some information from those emails.

The problem is that every email provider/client marks forwarded part differently: gmail marks with "--- Forwarded Message ---", outlook just adds "from:..., to:..., subject:..." part before the forwarded message and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such a special entity like a "forwarded email".

It is just an ordinary email that a particular email client decorated in some arbitrary way and sent to someone.

Based on what I've stated above - there is no a generic solution, since a "forwarded message" may be composed any way the client wants.

Comment: +1 And don't forget about the (zany) localized headers used by localized versions of Outkook, which might also be different between platforms and versions.